# Ajax POST with filename as parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I know how to do an Ajax POST to a PHP file which writes/creates a file on the server. But is it possible to send a parameter which tells the PHP how the file which should be created is named?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Javascript code add data to pass to php script:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/your_php_script.php',
    data: {
      filename: 'some_name'
    }
...
```

In your PHP script:

```
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you send a complete working code example?

Comment: This is it. Doesn't work for you? You can post your code and I can review it.

Comment: It works now, thank you :D